# Height state value not updating immediately and state value always one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-virtualized

I have a small project using `justified-layout` and `react-virtualized`,

I set the `width` and `height` of the `preview images` with the `useCallback` of `previewImageContainerRef` Ref. ( In the `<PreviewImage>` component [(`<Results> / <PreviewImgRow> / <PreviewImage>`) `components > albums > results > preview_image.js`], `ref={previewImageContainerRef} is in preview_image.js as well, located on <div> with className="c-flex-center picture-frame-wrapper"`)

```
    // useCallback > Ref : previewImageContainerRef
    const previewImageContainerRef = useCallback(node => {

        if (node !== null) {

            // Set > Preview Image Width
            props.setPreviewImageWidth(node.getBoundingClientRect().width);

            // Calculate > Preview Image Height
            let new_height = (node.getBoundingClientRect().width / defaultImageWidthRef.current ) * defaultImageHeightRef.current;

            // Set > Preview Image Height
            props.setPreviewImageHeight(new_height);

        }

    }, []);
```

The `useState` for `setPreviewImageWidth` and `setPreviewImageHeight`, are defined in the parent component (`<Results>` [`components > albums > results > Results.js`]):

```
  // Preview Image > Width & Height
  const [previewImageWidth, setPreviewImageWidth] = useState(0);
  const [previewImageHeight, setPreviewImageHeight] = useState(0);
```

`justifiedRowDetailsRef` is defined in `<Results>` component, it uses `useCallback` as well and it is one of the parent `<div>` wrapping around the `preview image` (`ref={justifiedRowDetailsRef}` is in  component [(`<Results> / <PreviewImgRow>`) `components > albums > results > PreviewImgRow.js`]):

```
  // useCallback > Ref : justifiedRowDetailsRef
  const justifiedRowDetailsRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {

      setJustifiedRowDetailsWidth(node.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      setJustifiedRowDetailsHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);

    }
  }, []);
```

The `useState` for `justifiedRowDetailsWidth` and `justifiedRowDetailsHeight` are defined in `<Result>` component:

```
  const [justifiedRowDetailsWidth, setJustifiedRowDetailsWidth] = useState(0);
  const [justifiedRowDetailsHeight, setJustifiedRowDetailsHeight] = useState(0);
```

`justifiedRowDetailsHeight` is used in the height calculations for multiple parent `<div>` wrapping the `preview image`

The problem I am facing is that the `justifiedRowDetailsHeight` value is only updated correctly when the `image` in the `<JustifiedBox>` component is clicked to expand the `second time` and after

Preview of the problem:

[image]

and here is my `codesandbox` link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-ride-qvquwv?file=/components/albums/results/Results.js

any asistance on this is greatly appreciated

**Edit:** I have commented out:

```
  // useCallback > Ref : justifiedRowDetailsRef
  const justifiedRowDetailsRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {

      setJustifiedRowDetailsWidth(node.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      setJustifiedRowDetailsHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);

    }
  }, []);
```

and replaced it with:

```
const justifiedRowDetailsRef = useRef(null);
```

and passed `setJustifiedRowDetailsWidth` and `setJustifiedRowDetailsHeight` to `<PreviewImgRow>` component, and added this `useEffect()` into it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (justifiedRowDetailsRef.current) {
      console.log("justifiedRowDetailsRef.current > NOT EMPTY");

      setJustifiedRowDetailsWidth(justifiedRowDetailsRef.current.offsetWidth);
      setJustifiedRowDetailsHeight(justifiedRowDetailsRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }
  }, [previewImageHeight, isPreviewShown]);
```

Now on first click of the `image`, the `height` is correct, but if I clicked on `images` with different dimension ( for example, the `square` image `keep calm and eat food`), the `height` of the `preview image` is still using the previous `preview image` height ( the `rectangle` height ) and one step behind

Steps to reproduce the bug:

Step1:

[image]

Step2:

[image]

Step3:

[image]

Step4:

[image]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. For me, the preview is shown with the reasonable height both on first and on further openings. Is the question still relevant?

Comment: Yeah the problem isn't being replicated for me too.

Comment: hi, thanks for the replies, I have updated the question with steps to reproduce the bug

Comment: any help/hint on this will be very much appreciated

Comment: You need to reduce the explanation. It's too long and many won't be interested to read. Add a TLDR to summarize in a few words, and only explaining what's the core issue is.

Comment: **Cannot reproduce the problem**, also the codesandbox takes too long to load and the code is polluted with unused imports and commented-out blocks. I would suggest you clean that up a bit for anyone who tries to help. I used Chrome, **could you check if you can reproduce the problem on the codesandbox provided** on your browser and on different browsers?